# React hooks : useMemo and useEffect has a Missing dependency when we are trying to call a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

`triggerData` function is used in multiple functions. So, if i place the function inside the `useEffect` to avoid missing dependencies then i can not call the `triggerData` outside the `useEffect` i.e., `buildData`.How can i avoid missing dependencies error?

```
useEffect(()=>{
 //api call
  if(something){
    triggerData(state, props);
  }
}[values]);

const triggerData = (state, props) => {
  return values + 1;
}

const buildData = () => {
  triggerData(state, props);
}
```

**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'triggerData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

When i add `triggerData` in the `useEffect`, i get the following error.
**`triggerData` was used before it was defined                                                                                                                                                                   no-use-before-define**

```
useEffect(()=>{
     //api call
      const triggerData = (values) => {
        return values + 1;
      }
      if(something){
        triggerData(values);
      }
    }[values, triggerData]);

    const buildData = () => {
      triggerData(values);
    }
```

Comment: does your trigger data use anything from state or prop?

Comment: The question unclear, any producible minimal example?

Comment: @AmitChauhan yes, it can use anything.

Comment: @DennisVash I have upated the question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use triggerData outside of useEffect you can use another hook called useCallback.

You don't need to pass props and state to function as it will be available from the parent's scope.

```
const triggerData = useCallback(() => {
  return values + 1;
}, [ /* pass required depedencies here */])

useEffect(()=>{
 //api call
  if(something){
    triggerData(); // don't pass state and props here
  }
}[values, triggerData]);

const buildData = () => {
  triggerData(); // dont pass state and props here
}
```

Comment: I tried the above answer but it says `triggerData` was used before it was defined at the end of `useEffect()`

Comment: you need to define triggerData before useEffect not after

Comment: i made the changes suggested, now an api is being called infinite times

Comment: what are you passing as dependencies?

Comment: local variables

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `triggerData` only inside the hook, then i will prefer declaring the function inside the `useEffect` hook. Like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  //api call
  const triggerData = (values) => {
     return values + 1;
  }
  if(something){
    triggerData(values);
  }
}, [values]);
```

You were missing something. You we declaring `triggerData` inside the hook and also passing it to `useEffect` that's why it complains about function already declared.

In case you really want to declare `triggerData` outside `useEffect` to use it somewhere else you can do it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 //api call
  if(something){
    triggerData(state, props);
  }
}, [values, triggerData]);

const triggerData = useCallback((state, props) => {
  return values + 1;
}, [state, props]);


const buildData = () => {
  triggerData(state, props);
}
```

In use `useCallback` provide the accurate params to get it invoked minimal according to the scenario. Let say, you are accessing `value` from state in `triggerData`. Then you can pass `state.value` rather than the whole `state`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: But, how can I access triggerdata from builddata?

Comment: In this case useEffect will run after every render.

Comment: @AmitChauhan Thanks. I was aware of `useCallback` and updated my answer accordingly.